# Searchable dropdown/select in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, searchable

I have a searchable dropdown (http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/) selector. I filled with jquery the options from database dinamically. but, when I change category, it keeps the previous items. (so when I toggle from category 1-3 to category 4-6, there are options 1-6)
If I try without this script, everything works fine (but it don't searchable).
I tried  `$(this).empty() and $("<select/>").empty()` every where in the source code, to empty the list, but there were no usefull result. 
So when I initialize the search plugin, it should clear first the `<select>`. http://jsfiddle.net/cociweb/RjVwh/3/

where should I put the `$("<select/>").empty();` or something like that into the [searchabledropdown-1.0.7.src.js](http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/jquery.searchabledropdown.js)?
!

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

`$('select option').remove()`;

This will clear all the options. After this add the new values.